# Restrict end user to edit content to some height and width in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any way to restrict the end user from editing content to some height and width.
Suppose if the ckeditor height is `200px` and width is `300px`, then end user should not be able to add more content with height and width. I have set **overflow hidden** in the html, but it is not working. Please help.